# Append Column to Spark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is my current code :

```py
impcomp = ['connectors', 'contract_no', 'document_confidentiality', 'document_type', 'drawing_no', 'equipment_specifications', 'external_drawings', 'is_psi', 'line_numbers', 'owner_no', 'plant', 'project_title', 'psi_category', 'revision', 'revision_date', 'revision_status', 'tags', 'unit']


for el in impcomp:
    df1 = df3.select(df[Pk[1]],posexplode_outer(df3[el]))
    df1 = df1.where(df1.pos !='1')
    df1 = df1.drop('pos')
    df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('col',el)
    dfu = df4.join(df1,df4.DocumentNo ==  df1.DocumentNo,"left")

display(dfu)
```

What i want is for the final dataframe to iterate to each and every element and append itself to main dataframe (dfu). But instead, my current code overwrite the previous element column, leaving the final dataframe (dfu) as: dfu + 'unit' column. is there any way for me to store the value for each column that was iterate in the for loop without overwriting the previous element?

expcted result:

---

### Document | Author | connectors | contract_no .........|unit|

A        |  AA    |   12       |   C13                 |Z12

current result:

---

### Document | Author | unit|

A        |  AA    |   Z12

thanks in advance

```
dfs = []
for el in impcomp:
    df1 = df3.select(df[Pk[1]],posexplode_outer(df3[el]))
    df1 = df1.where(df1.pos !='1')
    df1 = df1.drop('pos')
    df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed('col',el)
    dfs.append(df1[el])
df6 = reduce(df4.union(dfs))
```

i have tried this but it returns error :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jdf'

Comment: Instead of giving us code, give a sample dataframe  before transformation and the expected output after transformation. That way you get help faster.

Comment: @wwnde i already add the current output and expected output above. can u advise?